# VS Code launch.json into an actual command

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I want to make a Python script that transforms a part of VS Code `launch.json` into a normal command for a terminal. I need it to communicate with non-VSCode users. Here is the example:

```
import json

launch_json = '''
        {
            "name": "temp",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "script.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "args": ["abcd",
                     "--log", "log.txt"],
            "env": {"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":"0"},
        }
'''

d = json.loads(launch_json)
command = d["program"] + " " + " ".join(d["args"])
print(command)
```

If I run it, I have the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 12 column 9 (char 344)
```

How do I make the script?

Comment: Remove the trailing comma on the last property value (env)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra comma at the end of `launch_json`

```py
{
   "env": {"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":"0"}, <- should not be here
}
```

so just replace it with

```py
{
   "name": "temp",
   "type": "python",
   "request": "launch",
   "program": "script.py",
   "console": "integratedTerminal",
   "justMyCode": false,
   "args": ["abcd",
            "--log", "log.txt"],
   "env": {"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":"0"}
}
```